# Is there a ruby gem to interface the Newrelic API?

Tags: ruby, newrelic

I'm trying to search for this, but all I get is information on the ruby agent for Newrelic. I want to know if there's something that makes it easier to make API calls to a Newrelic account. I want to use ruby to delete servers from accounts after they've been killed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of gems you could use, but you could build a simple Ruby script that automates the removal of non-reporting servers from New Relic, as described here: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/feature-request-filter-by-servers/2279